# How to efficiently execute JavaScript functions when elements are inserted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dynamic

Initially, when the page loads, I search with jQuery for stuff like this:

```
<label for="first_name">name</label>
<input type="text" name="first_name" />
```

And change html to be fancier.

The problem becomes when I try to dynamically insert elements like these into DOM. Since nothing is binded to the newly created elements, I am not sure what's a proper way to run my "adjustement" functions. I wouldn't simply want to hack it and call `adjust_html1()`, `adjust_html2()`, etc manually right after inserting.

What is the most organized and efficient way to run code after html is inserted?

(sidenote: *would be even cooler if there's a way to run it only on new html*)

**Edit**: added a "for"

**Edit 2**: Here's my sample jQuery code that runs on document ready:

```
$('label').each(function() {
  /* do stuff */
});
```

Comment: *I search with jQuery stuff like this...* This is a misnomer, there is no jquery on the following lines. What does this mean in the context of what is in the question?

Comment: @JaredFarrish - I think he meant "I search with jQuery __for__ stuff like this".

Comment: @Justin - That's entirely possible...

Comment: @JaredFarrish I meant I search with jQuery for those elements. Edited.

Comment: @Jon - It's always better to provide the underlying/related code. `:)`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish good idea, because I have a question to one of the answers :)

Answer (score 2):

You could checkout the [livequery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery):

```
$('[name="first_name"]').livequery(function() {
    alert('A node with name=first_name was injected into the DOM');
    adjust(this);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) binding method.

> Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current
>   selector, now and in the future.

Comment: Note: This allows binding of event handlers to new elements. If you want actions to run at the time of _insertion_, it's probably better to run that code before insertion if possible, so the rendering engine doesn't have to reflow.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Yes `delegate()` can be faster in some cases, depending on the selectors, DOM tree, event bubbling/propagation needs, and a couple other advanced things. But yes, it's a good idea to point that method out as an alternative too.

Comment: @Mufasa so should I do something like this?
$('label').live('load', function() {});

Comment: This does not do what the question asked.  `.live()` does give them any notification of when new elements are added.  Furthermore `.load()` events do not work with `.live()`.  This question is not about event handlers for new objects, but about knowing when new objects have been added to the page so they can be styled/improved.

Comment: @JonDerring: No, not bind to the 'load' handler. This would be for binding 'click' handlers and such. Whether or not this is the right solution depends on what you're doing in the function. Are you adding event handlers (if so then, yes_, or are you manipulating CSS, data, etc. (if so see my other comment about doing this at the time of insertion, or the answer by @mre666)? More code would help give context and help us answer you more specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Create your html like this:

```
var elem = $('<p></p>').text('hello').appendTo(document.body);
adjust_html(elem);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, perhaps I didn't explain what I wanted correctly. The purpose is to basically be able to run a set of functions on newly inserted html - efficiently, without having to manually call them.

For now I am going to go with the code I wrote below. Initially, you have templates on your page, and you bind functions for certain selectors (that exist inside of your template) to all your templates. So that when you insert the template into the page, those selectors try to match inside of your template, and run binded functions.

The code below is neither efficient, nor optimized or thoroughly tested. So, I am not going to accept it as the final answer. It is just a sample solution, and kind of hacky anyway. But it works. I am sure [backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) or some plugin do it much better, so I'll wait for a JS guru to show the right way.

**As a sidenote:** I realize there's 2 disadvantages: **a)** the way of setting html has to be done through template object, rather than natural jQuery way, and **b)** template is inserted into DOM, and only then functions start running on it. My first version did work on the template before it was inserted, but some functions like `.replaceWith()` don't work exactly the same on strings as on DOM nodes. On the plus side, the code is tiny, and does just what I wanted.

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.template = {
            queue: {},
            set: function(container, content) {

                /* first insert content */
                container.html(content);

                /* now run a list of functions in the queue */
                $.each(this.queue, function(s, fs) {
                    var el = $(s, container);
                    for (var i = 0, len = fs.length; i < len; ++i)
                        el.each(fs[i]);
                });

            },
            bind: function(selector, func) {
                if (typeof this.queue[selector] === 'undefined')
                    this.queue[selector] = [];
                /* push function to queue for that specific selector */
                this.queue[selector].push(func);
            }
        };

        $(function() {

            var templateContents = $('#my-template').html();

            /* for each <label>, replace it with another <input> */
            template.bind('label[for="first_name"]', function() {
                $(this).replaceWith('<input type="text" name="last_name" value="last name" />');
            });

            $('a').click(function(e) {

                e.preventDefault();
                $('body').append('<div class="container"></div>');

                /* get the div that we just appended to body */
                var newDiv = $('.container').last();

                /* set that newDiv's html to templateContents, and run binded functions */
                template.set(newDiv, templateContents);

            });

        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script id="my-template" type="text/template">
        <label for="first_name">name</label>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" />
    </script>
    <a href="#">add dynamically</a>
</body>
</html>
```